# Rails one to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a one to many association between jobs and companies and it work fine now i want in the job show view to have a link to the company who has published the job for this in my job show view i put this code

```
 <p>
          <strong>company:</strong>
             <%= link_to @job.company_name, company_path %>
 </p>
```

but instead of going to `http://localhost:3000/companies/company_id` I’m redirecting to  `http://localhost:3000/companies/job_id`  where is the fault in my view

this is my routes

```
Ecole::Application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  resources :jobs

  resources :companies
  resources :posts, only: [:show, :create]

  devise_for :users

  root "welcome#index"


  get "profiles/show" 

  get '/profile/:id' => 'profiles#show', :as => :profile
  get 'profiles' => 'profiles#index'
```

Comment: Can you share the routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
 <%= link_to @job.company_name, company_path %>
```

With

```
 <%= link_to @job.company_name, company_path(@job.company) %>
```

Comment: i have tried the same solution but doesn't work and now it work maybe there is some magic hhhh, thank you very much

Comment: @user3304070 I have magic fingers that puts magic behind what I type. :)

Comment: Hi  Kirti Thorat can you please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111579/favorite-system-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be passing the company id as a param for the company_path route. Try with company_path(:id=> company_id) with company_id being the targeted company id.